# Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder Foreign Key Issue

Tags: php, laravel

In **route.php**, i tried to make a test as below. So, which mean it should be link the **cats** with the **products** table, right?

```
Route::get('test',function (){
return App\products::with('cats');
```

});

And then in **products.php**, I put the code as below and it cause the error. Problem is the **products** table has the **cat_id** column. I wonder what is the error...

```
public function cats(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\cats', 'cat_id');
```

}

Comment: You have to execute the query: `return App\products::with('cats')->get();`

Comment: Oh I see!!! YEAH IS WORKS!